# "SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not String objects"

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database

I keep getting the exception

> The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not String objects

while executing the following code:

```cs
string StrQuery;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=SanFransiscoData;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"))
{
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
       // SqlParameter author = new SqlParameter("@author", dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        comm.Parameters.Add("@author", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comm.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        comm.Parameters.Add("@genre", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comm.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Float);
        comm.Parameters.Add("@publish_date", SqlDbType.Date);
        comm.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        comm.Parameters.Add("@bookid", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            StrQuery = "INSERT INTO BooksData VALUES(@author,@title,@genre,@price,@publish_date,@description,@bookid)";
            comm.Parameters.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            comm.Parameters.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            comm.Parameters.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            comm.Parameters.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value));
            comm.Parameters.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value));
            comm.Parameters.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
            comm.Parameters.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
            comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: The error message is straightforward. You should not be adding strings to the Parameters collection. Create a new `SqlParameter` object and add that to the collection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not DBNull objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425361/the-sqlparametercollection-only-accepts-non-null-sqlparameter-type-objects-not)

Comment: In my case, I have used `cmd.Parameters.AddRange` and pass List<object>, This list should contain SqlParameter, but by mistake, I have passed one string object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `Add` method, you are trying to add a new parameter. What you want to do is to assign value. So change this:

```
comm.Parameters.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

to this:

```
comm.Parameters["@author"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Similarly for the other parameters.

Answer (score 188):

I tried all the above-mentioned steps but nothing helps.

Finally found and fixed it by changing the namespace

> **using System.Data.SqlClient** to **using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient**

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/introduction-microsoft-data-sqlclient-namespace?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped.
The type 'SqlParameter' exists in both namespaces that Dah Sra mentioned.
And System.Data.SqlClient goes first in intellisence helper in Visual Studio.

Comment: I think System.Data.SqlClient is being [retired](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/).

Comment: Swapped the dependencies and got same error, but in different DLL:
_The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter type objects, not System.String objects._

Answer (score 17):

I replaced my reference to System.Data.SqlClient with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
corrected the using statements and my problems went away

In my .csproj  I now have

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

But I also found I had use of the following scenario where I created a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter

```
    public static List<T> RunQuery<T>(ApiDbContext context, string query, Func<DbDataReader, T> map, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        var cn = context.Database.GetDbConnection();
        var oldState = cn.State;
        if (cn.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed)) { cn.Open(); }

        using (var command = cn.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            foreach (var param in parameters)
            {
                var p = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = param.ParameterName, Value = param.Value, SqlDbType = param.SqlDbType
                };
                command.Parameters.Add(p);
            }
            if (cn.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed)) { cn.Open(); }
            var entities = new List<T>();
            using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (result.Read())
                {
                    entities.Add(map(result));
                }
            }

            if (oldState.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed) && cn.State == ConnectionState.Open) { cn.Close(); }
            return entities;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I honestly thought there's something wrong with visual studio but then I tried casting one to the other.

Answer (score 10):

I had been getting the same error and had to use `AddWithValue` like this...

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@columnToUpdate, newValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@conditionalColumn, conditionalValue);
```

Comment: But AddWithValue will generate different length of parameters for SQL Server and different execution plans will be created. It's better to add the parameter and specify the length (example: searching for @name='Alex' or searching for @name='Martin' will generate a parameter of VARCHAR(4) for Alex and VARCHAR(6) for Martin and different execution plans in SQL Server)

Comment: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection no longer has AddWithValue

Comment: Don't use AddWithValue [link](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 2):

Try below

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@author", SqlDbType.VarChar);
comm.Parameters["@author"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, but mine was doing an object[2] = object[1] as SqlParameters, similar to what was being tried.

Just to add to the thread, I have this simple object array of SqlParameters added from a method like this,

```
    private SqlParameter GetGenericParamsObject(string name, object data)
    {
        return new SqlParameter(name, SetSqlDataType(data.GetType().ToString())) { Direction = Input, Value = data };
    }
```

Where there is a simple switch for the SetSqlDataType(), i.e. SqlDbType.Int is one of the return types to set it.

Then I run

```
    private static void ExecuteSqlCommand(DbContext dbContext, string sql, params object[] sqlParameters)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dbContext.Database.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                dbContext.Database.Connection.Open();
            var cmd = dbContext.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            foreach (var param in sqlParameters)
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

This helps with casting to the proper data type and moves the param name, datatype and object out of the command method for easier debugging and then just adding the entire SqlParameter to the cmd.Parameters.

Answer (score 1):

For any future readers of this question - the examples deal with `.Add()`, but `.Remove()` will also throw this error if not used correctly. The proper way to use `.Add()`, as has been documented by others is :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Key", "Value");
```

The proper way to use `.Remove()` is:

```
cmd.Parameters.Remove(command.Parameters["Key"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error when I was using

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(pars)
```

where `pars` was a an array of `SqlParameter`. The issue was that I was using the `Add()` function but I should've used `AddRange()` instead.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(pars)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following simple solution works for me:

```
SqlCommand command = ...
command.Parameters.Add(parameterPlaceholder, SqlDbType.Char);
command.Parameters[parameterPlaceholder].Value = (object)parameterValue ?? DBNull.Value;
```

Replacing a null value with "DBNull.Value" is the key. Don't forget to adapt the SqlDbType to your needs, in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error using System.Data.Entity.Database

[image: sqlquery]

In that case with EF 6.4 I needed to use something like

```
  var parameters = new List<SqlParameter> parameters  // using System.Data.SqlClient
  sql = $"{sql} and ( headkey like @headkey)";
  parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@headkey", $"%{headKey}%") { DbType = DbType.String });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this!! It would help

I've been trying this way in my project, it solve my problem

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@author", SqlDbType.VarChar));

StrQuery = "INSERT INTO BooksData 
VALUES(@author,@title,@genre,@price,@publish_date,@description,@bookid)";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```