# Issue running EF6 "SqlQuery<T>()" in the context of .NET Core 3.x

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, .net-4.0

I have a .NET Framework 4.x class library that leverages Entity Framework 6. Up until recently it has been leveraged in another 4.x based application but more recently it's been used in a .NET Core 3.x Azure function. Nothing has been changed in the class library and most aspects seem to work as expected with the exception of methods that accept `SqlParameter`s, in particular `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>()`.

The problem that I'm running into seems to be very similar to [what happens when using EF Core with .NET Core 3.x without updating from `System.Data.SqlClient` to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705767/sqlparametercollection-only-accepts-non-null-sqlparameter-type-objects-not-str), except it flips the problem on its head. The exception message is:

```
   The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects.
```

However, all documentation that I've come across states that EF 6 *is* compatible with .NET Core 3.x but *is not* compatible with `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`. I'm most certainly using `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter` and I can't see anywhere where the app is dipping into `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, as illustrated by this partial stack trace:

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.ValidateType(Object value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.AddRange(Array values)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateStoreCommand(String commandText, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryInternal[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass186_0`1.<ExecuteStoreQueryReliably>b__1()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass186_0`1.<ExecuteStoreQueryReliably>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryReliably[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery[TElement](String commandText, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass111_0`1.<ExecuteSqlQuery>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   <<a bunch of our custom stuff>>
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidMethodInvoker`2.InvokeAsync(TReflected instance, Object[] arguments) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\VoidMethodInvoker.cs:line 21
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.<InvokeAsync>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs:line 52
```

EDIT: Here's the pared down code from the solution...

In the .NetCore 3.1 Function (v3):

using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MyProject.Services;

namespace MyProject.Functions
{
public class MyFunction
{
private readonly MyDbContext _ctx;

```
    public MyFunction(MyDbContext ctx)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
    }


    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public override void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%QueueName%", Connection = "%ConnectionString%")]
        Message msg,
        ILogger log)
    {
        var service = new MyService();

        service.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

}

In the .NET 4.8 class library:

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyProject.Services
{
public class MyService
{
private readonly MyDbContext _context;

```
    public MyService(MyDbContext ctx)
    {
        _context = ctx;
    }


    public void DoStuff()
    {
        //this works
        var lineItems1 = _context.LineItems.Where(li => li.Description == "something arbitrary").ToList();

        //this gives the exception and stack trace from the original post
        var lineItems2 = _context.Database.SqlQuery<LineItem>(
            "SELECT * FROM LineItems WHERE Description = @Description",
            new[] { new SqlParameter("@Description", "something arbitrary") }).ToList();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: just checked `Net Core 3.1` works fine with `EF 6` and `db.Database.SqlQuery` with `SqlParameter`. So it should be something with Azure Functions

Comment: Please oh please share your code...